# libGDX 3D rotate ModelInstance to the second one with a coefficient of rotation speed

Tags: java, 3d, frameworks, libgdx

I'm working on 3D tower defence and I need some help with rotation of a ModelInstance.
How to rotate the ModelInstance to the second one with a coefficient of rotation speed.

For example: rotate base(or weapon) to enemy

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually you should never rotate a `ModelInstance` to face another `ModelInstance`, but you should rotate it to an angle given by the gamelogic.
That means, that you should sepperate the logic and the view.
In this case the logic needs to store the `currentAngle` and the `desiredAngle`, as well as a `rotationSpeed`.
The `desiredAngle` can be calculated out of the `position`s of the `Tower` and the `Enemy`.
In the `update(delta)` you can then say:

```
if (desiredAngle > currentAngle)
    currentAngle+=rotationSpeed*delta;
```

The same for the negative rotation and ensure to keep rotation between 0 and 360°.

You can then rotate the `ModelInstance` to the given `currentAngle` by rotating its `Matrix4 transform`, i gues the `rotate(float axisX, float axisY, float axisZ, float degrees)` should be the rigth one.